# Sort using apache spark for text input

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark

I want to sort the data using spark-shell (scala).

Input is like (EDIT - first column can contains two spaces)

```
AQWD  11BC23  A12A
ZXDM  33QWSD  CC12
  DM  EEZM33  FFZ2
```

I am trying to use 
sc.textFile("input.txt")

Now I want to sort the data using first column only.
I know I need to use sortByKey() but which transformation or action should I apply first so that I can use sortByKey() ? I am getting error of sortByKey is not member of rdd.RDD Array[String] by using below code which doesn't seem right

```
val lines = sc.textFile("input.txt")
val sort =  lines.map(_.Split("  ")).sortByKey()
```

Expected output

```
  DM  33QWSD  CC12    
AQWD  11BC23  A12A
BCDM  EEZM33  FFZ2
```

As spaces has ascii value of 32 it will be at the top and then remaining sorting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sortByKey()` is a so called [OrderedRDDFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/OrderedRDDFunctions.html). They are only available for `RDD` which contain tuples `(key,value)`. Your `RDD` will contain `Array[String]`. If you want to do it your way you can do it like this:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("input.txt")
val sort =  lines.map(_.split("  ")).map(arr => (arr(0),arr.mkString("  "))).sortByKey()
```

edit: yes you can make those 2 maps in one step, I find this more readable :-)

You can also do it like this:

```
scala> lines.sortBy[String]( (line:String) => line.split("  ")(0), true, 1 ).foreach(println)
AQWD  11BC23  A12A
BCDM  EEZM33  FFZ2
ZXDM  33QWSD  CC12
```

@Edit: if your key is different you just need to include it in your logic. For instance if all your delimiters are double spaces you can change the above code to:

```
lines.map(_.split("  ")).map(arr => (arr(0) + "  " + arr(1),arr.mkString("  ")))
```

Or the second one:

```
lines.sortBy[String]( (line:String) => { val split = line.split("  "); split(0) + "  " + split(1) }, true, 1 )
```

Comment: Can we do without using sortByKey() ? I thought we can only sort using sortBykey(). My main purpose is to sort the data using first column

Comment: @ViyatGandhi yes see my edit, you need to use a different method

Comment: Thanks!! ... so this is essentially use of scala. Is there any way I can make use of spark functions and do the sorting? (any of the map or reduce and some sorting at the end ). Because in future i need to sort big file using this.

Comment: @ViyatGandhi not this is not the sort from Scala, it's a Spark `sortBy` from the `RDD` and is doing exactly what you are asking for. You can see it in the documentation https://goo.gl/GmVfYQ

Comment: @ViyatGandhi Mateusz is right ! How would you want to sort by a key if you haven't define a key ?

Comment: @ViyatGandhi This answer actually answers your question, so please accept and upvote !

Comment: @ Mateusz Dymczyk my bad. Sorry for late reply. One last question, how can we save the output in text file as in same input format. after doing sort.collect() i can see output is Array (String,String) and second string contains the whole answer.

Comment: @Mateusz Dymczyk what if my key contains double space and i want that spaces to consider in sorting ?

Comment: @ViyatGandhi if you use my second approach you will get `Array[String]` after `collect` instead. Or in the first approach you can use `map(_._2)` before `collect()`. As for your second question are all other word breaks also double spaces? Anyway see my edit.